# Delete records, affected by another query

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all records that are affected by this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct news_id) AS TotalRecords, country 
FROM upload_news 
WHERE [upload_time] BETWEEN GetDate()-7 AND GetDate() 
GROUP BY country
```

I have no idea how to write query about this.

Comment: You can't do it with one query because what you're getting as a result is a number (from `COUNT`). You'll have to do it with another query: `DELETE FROM upload_news WHERE [upload_time] between GetDate()-7 AND GetDate()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all the rows that satisfy the predicate in your query...

remove the **`GROUP BY`** clause and replace the **`SELECT <expression_list>`** with the **`DELETE`** keyword...

But, this doesn't appear to be MySQL syntax. The square braces around the identifer, and the "`-7`" following the `GETDATE()` function make this look like SQL Server (Transact-SQL) syntax.

This would remove all the rows from `upload_news` with an `upload_time` value within the specified range.

```
DELETE FROM upload_news
 WHERE [upload_time] BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GetDate()
```

You can replace the **`DELETE`** with **`SELECT *`** and that will return all of the rows that would be deleted from the `upload_news` table. Be aware that foreign key constraints and/or triggers can cause rows in other tables to be affected (removed, updated and/or inserted)